# Why 0 is in the output?

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   vector<vector<int> >a(2);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        int m;
        cout<<"Enter number of elements on the row:"<<endl;
        cin>>m;
        vector<int> b(m);
        cout<<"Element:"<<endl;

         for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
         {
             int k;
             cin>>k;
             b.push_back(k)//if i use b[j]=k; here the zeros don't appear.
             //cout<<b[j];
         }
         a.push_back(b);
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
            for(unsigned int j=0;j<a[i].size();j++)
                cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Why does zero appear in the output?

The output should be without zeros.

In the second `push_back` function, if I use `b[j]` then zeros don't appear.

Comment: Can you tell me what you think `vector<int> b(m);` does? How many elements does `b` contain after being initialized? What are those elements?

Comment: B contains m elements and if they all were set to zero then why isn't it same for vector a?

Comment: You add two empty rows before adding any real rows. Why not just directly insert since you pre-sized it: `a[j].push_back(k)`.

Comment: @Coder124 Because `a` contains `vector<int>`, not `int`. `a` contains two default-constructed `vector<int>`s, which are both empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did the code directly inserting elements then i thought to try the pushback function. I am new to this so i don't know much

Comment: @Coder124 `vector<vector<int>>a(2); std::cout << a.size();`  What is outputted? Then change to this: `vector<vector<int>>a; std::cout << a.size();`  What is outputted there?  See the difference?  Now what does `push_back` do?  It adds *another* item to the back of the vector -- it doesn't replace an item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are initializing `a` with 2 blank `vector`s in it and then pushing 2 populated `vector`s into it.

And you are initializing `b` with `m` number of default zeros and then pushing `m` user-input integers into it.

You should not be initializing either `vector` with a value in its constructor. That pushes default values into the `vector`, which is throwing off your results. In this case, simply remove the constructor values and let `push_back()` handle the adds for you.

If you want to preallocate a `vector`'s memory without adding values to it, use its `reserve()` method instead, eg:

```
vector<vector<int> >a;
a.reserve(2);
...
vector<int> b;
b.reserve(m);
```

Otherwise, if you do use the constructor to pre-fill the `vector`s with defaults, then
you need to change your loops to use `vector::operator[]` instead of `vector::push_back()`, eg:

```
vector<vector<int> >a(2);
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    ... 
    vector<int> b(m);

    for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        ...
        b[j] = k;
    } 

    a[i] = b;
}
```

Comment: But 'a 'doesn't have the problem of adding default values.

Comment: @Coder124 Yes, it does. `a(2)` adds 2 blank vectors to `a`. And then the code adds 2 more vectors to `a`. The final output loop then sees 4 `vector`s, 2 of which are empty, but `endl` is still output after each one

Comment: Oh thanks now i understand more about vectors. I didn't notice a since i got the expected output but printing something after each iteration showed it iterated more times.